# Как получить папку из ресурсов

Tags: java, spring-boot

Spring Boot приложение. Вызываю в нем командную строку:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command,null,directory)
```

Где `directory` это должен быть `File("path to folder")`. В папке `resources` лежит папка с файлами, из которой собственно и нужно запустить команду. 
Вопрос в том как правильно передать `directory` во время выполнения, если это приложение собирается в executable jar и будет запускаться просто из командной строки.

```
File directory = new File(getClass().getResource("resources/directory").toExternalForm());
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command,null,directory);
```

Так не работает.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю вам это должно помочь:

```
@Service
public class YuorService {

    private static final String PATH = "/file.txt";

    private String data;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(PATH);
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

        data = bufferedReader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining());

        bufferedReader.close();
        inputStreamReader.close();
        inputStream.close();
    }

}
```

Еще есть такой вариант:

```
@Service
public class YourService {

    private static final String SRC = "src";
    private static final String[] PATH_TO_FILE = {"main", "resources", "file.txt"};

    private File file;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        Path path = Paths.get(SRC, PATH_TO_FILE);
        logFile = new File(path.toUri().getPath());

    }

}
```

Comment: Да, только дело в том что мне нужно создать файл, в котором ссылка на фолдер будет, грубо говоря. Т.е. new File("dir"), а не new File("dir/somethig.txt").

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь специализированным классом `ClassPathResource`

```
ClassPathResource imgFile = new ClassPathResource("/META-INF/resources/static/image/",
                Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
```